# Get Row and Colum position of a Grid populated by an ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make a minesweeper game using wpf. I designed the game board as an grid of buttons using the following code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateLevel2">
        <Button Content="{Binding}" Height ="30" Width="40" Click ="Execute"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key ="DataTemplateLevel1">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource ="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplateLevel2}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ItemsControl x:Name ="Field" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplateLevel1}" />
</Grid>
```

and

```
List<List<int?>> buttonGrid = new List<List<int?>>();
for (int r = 0; r < Rows; r++)
{
    buttonGrid.Add(new List<int?>());
    for (int c = 0; c < Cols; c++)
    {
        buttonGrid[r].Add(null);
    }
}

InitializeComponent();

Field.ItemsSource = buttonGrid;
```

.

The problem is that when I click a button, my event handler needs to know the row and column of the button, but `Grid.GetRow` and `Grid.GetColumn` always return 0. I think this is because the Grid only contains the one ItemsControl. How can I get meaningful row and column values while still allowing for dynamic grid sizes?

Comment: The children of the ItemsControl are not directly children of the Grid. You could give them Grid.Row and Grid.Column values all day long and it would have no effect, because they are not children of a Grid that has multiple rows and columns defined. Instead, they are children of the StackPanel created by your `ItemsPanelTemplate`. No grid. Only StackPanel. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Since the Grid is not going to provide index, I would like to get the index from the ItemsControls. The click event handler knows which button was pressed, I just don't know how to ask the ItemsControl for its position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read up about [what a `Grid` does in WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid(v=vs.110).aspx). Your guess is wildly off base. Those buttons don't have `Grid.Row` or `Grid.Column` values because you didn't explicitly give them any. Furthermore, it would be a waste of time if you did, because they're not in a `Grid`. They're in a `ContentPresenter` (betcha didn't see that coming!) which is in a `StackPanel` created by your `ItemsPanelTemplate`.

You don't need to do any of that anyway. Here's what you can do.

First, write a simple class to represent the grid cells in your `buttonGrid`. An `int?` can't hold all the information you need.

```
public class GridCellItem
{
    public GridCellItem()
    {
    }

    public GridCellItem(int r, int c, int? v = null)
    {
        Row = r;
        Col = c;
        Value = v;
    }

    public int Row { get; set; }
    public int Col { get; set; }
    public int? Value { get; set; }
}
```

Next, populate the grid with very similar code to what you've got:

```
List<List<GridCellItem>> buttonGrid = new List<List<GridCellItem>>();
for (int r = 0; r < Rows; r++)
{
    buttonGrid.Add(new List<GridCellItem>());

    for (int c = 0; c < Cols; c++)
    {
        buttonGrid[r].Add(new GridCellItem(r, c));
    }
}

Field.ItemsSource = buttonGrid;
```

Once you've got all that, here's how your mouse click handler gets the Row, Column, and Value information from the item that was clicked:

```
private void Execute(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var cellItem = ((Button)sender).DataContext as GridCellItem;

    //  Replace this with code that does something useful, of course. 
    MessageBox.Show($"User clicked cell at row {cellItem.Row}, column {cellItem.Col}, with value {cellItem.Value}");
}
```